# How to remove or hide certain parts out of a Contact List

Tags: sharepoint-online, view, contacts, ellipses

[image]

Dear Experts,
I have a contact list and there are certain parts that I would like to have removed or hidden. I have put a picture as attach. Its the checkbox and de 3 dots. How can I remove or hide these?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps:

1. Go to **List Settings**.
2. Click on the View you want to modify from **Views** section at the bottom.
3. **To Remove ellipses(three dots)** --> Un-select checkbox before "Naam (linked to item with edit menu)" and select checkbox for **Naam(linked to item)**.
4. **To Remove checkbox** --> Scroll down on the same view settings page up to **Tabular View** Section and expand it --> Un-select the checkbox of **Allow individual item checkboxes**.
5. Click OK.

Comment: Very odd. I did the solution that was posted above. But everything remains the same.

Comment: I did unselect checkbox of Allow individual item checkboxes but the check sign is still displayed

Comment: How many views are there in list? Are you checking in the same view where you have made the changes? Can you please add screenshot of view settings if possible?

Comment: Just one view. The default view